# How to "check" GtkCellRendererToggle?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I would like a simple checkbox to "check" when I click it but am finding this very tricky, and there are almost no examples on the internet!

```
GtkTreeView *tree_view;
GtkListStore *list_store;
GtkTreeModelFilter *filter_model;

static int populate_row_callback (void *data, int colCount, char *values[], char *colNames[]) {
  GtkTreeIter row_iter;
  gtk_list_store_append (list_store, &row_iter);
  gtk_list_store_set (list_store, &row_iter, COL_DOWNLOAD, TRUE,
                                             ... // more cols
                                             -1);
  return 0;
}

void populate_grid () {
  gtk_list_store_clear (list_store);
  syn_get_data (populate_row_callback); // gets data from sqlite
}


static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data) {
  GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file ("window.ui");
  window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window"));
  search_toggle = GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "search_toggle"));
  search_bar = GTK_SEARCH_BAR (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "search_bar"));
  search_entry = GTK_SEARCH_ENTRY (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "search_entry"));
  tree_view = GTK_TREE_VIEW (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "tree_view"));
  list_store = GTK_LIST_STORE (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "list_store"));
  filter_model = GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER (gtk_tree_model_filter_new (GTK_TREE_MODEL (list_store), NULL));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);
  g_object_unref (builder);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  populate_grid ();
  gtk_tree_model_filter_set_visible_func (filter_model, search_filter_func, NULL, NULL);
  gtk_tree_view_set_model (tree_view, GTK_TREE_MODEL (filter_model));

  gtk_main ();
}

void download_toggled (GtkCellRendererToggle *cell, gchar *path_string, gpointer user_data) {
  GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model (tree_view);
  GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_string (path_string);

  GtkTreeIter rowIter;
  if (gtk_tree_model_get_iter (model, &rowIter, path)) {
    gboolean checked = gtk_cell_renderer_toggle_get_active (cell);
    // gtk_cell_renderer_toggle_set_active (cell, !checked); // effects every row!

    gtk_list_store_set (list_store, &rowIter, 0, !checked, -1); // causes runtime critical warning
  }
}
```

I also tried using the `GtkListStore` inside the same handler:

```
gtk_list_store_set (list_store, &rowIter, 0, !checked, -1);
```

But that does not work and I get:
`Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_list_store_set_valist: assertion 'iter_is_valid (iter, list_store)' failed`

This is because the `Iter` rowIter is not fetched using the row_store, but then again, I cannot fetch it using that because it does not have a get method...

Comment: have you tried using `gtk_tree_model_get_iter_from_string()` and passing the model directly, without `gtk_tree_view_get_model()`? These are the only differences I see between your code and mine, which is guaranteed to be working.

Comment: FYI, this is how my code works: `gtk_tree_model_get(GTK_TREE_MODEL(model), &rowIter, 0, &checked, -1); gtk_list_store_set(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &rowIter, 0, !checked, -1);`

Comment: @hidefromkgb Yes I saw similar code on a stackoverflow question but it did not work for me because I had different set of args passed into the toggle function. Please if you could post your answer in full.

Comment: OK. When I return home I\`ll put together a minimal example.

Comment: Can you show the full code for the second snippet? If it's running inside the `if` block, there shouldn't be a reason for the iter to be invalid...

Comment: @andlabs I have posted more fuller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GtkListStore is embedded in a GtkTreeModelFilter, so any GtkTreePaths and GtkTreeIters you make will be specific to the GtkTreeModelFilter. In order to be able to modify the underlying GtkTreeModel, you will have to turn the GtkTreeIter for the GtkTreeModelFilter into a GtkTreeIter for the underlying GtkListStore using the [`gtk_tree_model_filter_convert_iter_to_child_iter()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModelFilter.html#gtk-tree-model-filter-convert-iter-to-child-iter) function. Call it inside the if block in your original code's `download_toggled()`.

The same will apply if you ever add a GtkTreeModelSort into the equation. If you use both, you'll have to call the equivalent `iter_to_child_iter` function for both, in the correct order — it's like peeling an onion, layer by layer.